# Configuration mod fcgid for large process & Large Site

Tags: php, apache, centos7, mod-fcgid

I need some advice from an expert apache **fcgid**, the best settings for **fcgid** to be able to handle large process and long **php** process.

> ***Kvm Vps***
>
> 6GB Ram
>
> 4 Cpu Core
>
> Centos 7 x64
>
> Apache 2.4.6
>
> Php 7

The current configuration on ***/etc/httpd/conf.d/fcgid.conf***

```
# This is the Apache server configuration file for providing FastCGI support
# through mod_fcgid
#
# Documentation is available at
# http://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html

# Use FastCGI to process .fcg .fcgi & .fpl scripts
AddHandler fcgid-script fcg fcgi fpl

# Sane place to put sockets and shared memory file
FcgidIPCDir /run/mod_fcgid
FcgidProcessTableFile /run/mod_fcgid/fcgid_shm
FcgidMinProcessesPerClass  0
FcgidMaxProcessesPerClass  8
FcgidMaxProcesses          100
FcgidIdleTimeout           60
FcgidProcessLifeTime       120
FcgidIdleScanInterval      10
```

Tanks very much...

Comment: How large and how long?

Answer (score 1):

This is my config from a cPanel/WHm server with about 350 cPanel active accounts (sites/domains/emails etc).

The sever is a vmware VM with 8 cpu cores, 8 GB RAM, 6 GB swap

```
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
    FcgidMaxRequestLen 1073741824
    FcgidOutputBufferSize 1073741824
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
      FcgidMaxRequestsPerProcess 500
      FcgidMaxProcesses 300
      FcgidConnectTimeout 180
      FcgidIOTimeout 2000
      FcgidIdleTimeout 60
      FcgidFixPathinfo 1
      FcgidProcessLifeTime 60
      FcgidIdleScanInterval 15
      FcgidBusyTimeout 180
      FcgidBusyScanInterval 30
      FcgidErrorScanInterval 3
      FcgidZombieScanInterval 3
      FcgidMinProcessesPerClass  0
      #FcgidMaxProcessesPerClass 3
</IfModule>
```

The server works perfectly fine!

Comment: Sir bogdan tanks for replay, i need for single site sir. Do you have idea?

Are you using cloudlinux?

Comment: Yes I am using CloudLinux. You can use the same config, it will works the same for one single site or multiple sites. That's the config from a CentOS 6.x server with CloudLinux and EasyApache3. EasyApache 4 comes by default with apache mod_lsapi not with mod_fcgid. If you use mod_fcgid with apache you can use the config I have provided. Give it a try!

Comment: thanks for this, now my logs a little bit clear